# How do i configure ssh to listen in port 22 but restrict use only if some kind of tunneling is provided?

Tags: ssh, firewall, ssh-tunnel

So i have this ssh server, which is currently listening in some port lets say 5003(just for the sake of it) i can easily acess it with using the flag in unix and correctly putting the port.

This would all be fine, but in my college they block pretty much all the ports except the most commonly used ones(one being 22 related to SSH) i still want to make it so that port 33933 is open, but i want a behaviour so that if i connect directly to port 22 it returns some kind of error, but if i add some kind of tunnel through port 22 but while ending up locally on port 33933 would give sucess all

I've tried ListenAdress :22 with port set to 5003 although just locked myself out of ssh, i've tried various configs relating to local tunneling and remote although they don't seem to be working even when im doing it at home where i don't have any kind of restrictions( i activated TCPtunneling)

The reason why i want to use a port other than the default is that although i have it set to use RSA auth i want to obfuscate the port in order to make it a bit more difficult in case of a deliberate attack(its reasonable to assume SSH is almost always in the default port)

Is this a reasonable fear or am i shooting myself on the foot? if its possible to do somehow listen on port 22 but only accept the "request" if some kind of redirect on the client is performed?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Serverfault!

Using a tunnel usually means that the connection is not coming from "anywhere", but from a defined tunnel exit server. This might be a dedicated server, or simply the `localhost` (when using PuTTY, for example). Now, you have at least two options.

**First,** you can use a firewall (such as `iptables`) to restrict access to port 22 to those machines who provide the tunnel exit.

**Second,** you can go into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and edit the `Listen...` parameters, see [sshd manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html). What you probably find in the configuration by default is this:

```
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
```

Comment: mmm the last time i attempted to do so i got locked out no mather what combination of of ports addresses, etc...
but then again i typed in ListenAddress 127.0.0.1:22

Comment: also i forgot to mention im using linux ssh client to connect

Comment: When you are already using `ListenAddress 127.0.0.1:22` and no other listening, then the port 22 shall not be exposed to anything that is not tunneled. However, I wonder what you use to open the tunnel to the local machine, if not via port 22? Most commonly, you open a tunnel via PuTTY through port 22 to access some other port, for example SQL. Or do you have another VPN tunnel exit in the network that you are using to access the machine?